# What is a space elevator and who originated the idea?

Tags: technology

I was reading an old Science Fiction Chronicles the other day and came across the term "space elevator" as in, this would be a good place for one -- but what are they? The author didn't really explain what he meant or what it would look like, what it was for.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's an elevator that goes from the surface of the earth (has to be some point on the equator) to (a bit beyond) geosynchronous orbit, 22,000 miles up. It's for getting stuff into space much more cheaply than rocket launchers.

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) for much more information.

The concept was originated by Konstantin Tsiolkovsky in the late 19th century, but didn't appear in SF until 1979, when *The Fountains of Paradise* by Arthur C Clarke and *The Web Between the Worlds* by Charles Sheffield both appeared at pretty much the same time.

Comment: Yup, not as dumb as it sounds, all we need is a really - no *really* - strong rope :)

Comment: actually serious research is going on about the issue.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator

Comment: It's more about the strength-to-weight rather then the absolute strength.

Comment: Carbon nanotubes were being touted a few years back.

Comment: They considered spider silk!

Comment: Amazing that someone in the 19th century, when elevators themselves were far from commonplace, would have this idea which I still have trouble grasping -- just don't see how they could work.

Comment: https://sfdictionary.com/view/151/space-elevator

Comment: I remember describing the concept to someone in 1977; probably I had seen it in *Galaxy* or *F&SF* in 1976.

Comment: @releseabe Not that amazing. If you didn't understand precisely how an elevator worked, beyond "it goes up and down", then the idea of just making the elevator "taller" is pretty simple. Really, the idea of "tall building go up" goes back thousands of years to the Tower of Babel.

Comment: @chepner: I think the idea of a cable suspended from a satellite is a tremendous conceptual leap from a building with a foundation in the ground.